# dynamically fetching dynamic variable's value from properties file

Tags: variables, unix

Below unix commands works:

```
export myTempVar=myTempVar1
export myTempVar1=myTempVar2

eval echo '$'$myTempVar
```

This correctly prints myTempVar2.

However, what if `myTempVar1=myTempVar2` is present in a properties file instead of directly in the script.

So my script will have

```
. $MYDIR/myProperties.properties
myTempVar=myTempVar1
myTempVar3=eval echo '$'$myTempVar
```

Above lines are not working and the value of myTempVar3 is not coming as myTempVar2.

`myProperties.properties` is having below line:

```
myTempVar1=myTempVar2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using indirection is far safer than eval:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $MYDIR/myProperties.properties # myTempVar1=myTempVar2
myTempVar=myTempVar1
myTempVar3=${!myTempVar}
echo $myTempVar3
```

*Gives:*

```
myTempVar2
```

and you don't need the echo in eval:

```
eval myTempVar3='$'$myTempVar
```